# Set marker to the center of circle (current location)

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

I use Google Map Android API v2 in my app and I have a little problem as in the picture below but have no ideas how to fix it. I set marker to current location of device but its now in the center of circle. I want to **set marker to the center of the circle**. Is it possible or not?

**Thanks for any help!**

**Code that I used**:

```
// Showing status
if(status!= ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available

    int requestCode = 10;
    Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
    dialog.show();

}else { // Google Play Services are available

    // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of activity_location.xml
    SupportMapFragment mSupportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
    mGoogleMap = mSupportMapFragment.getMap();

    // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
    mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
    LocationManager mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    // Getting the name of the best provider
    String provider = mLocationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    // Getting Current Location
    Location location = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    if(location!=null){
        onLocationChanged(location);
    }
    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);

    // Getting latitude of the current location
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();

    // Getting longitude of the current location
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();

    // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
    LatLng mLatLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    //Add Marker to current location of devise
    mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(mLatLng)
            .title("Geolocation system")
            .snippet("Your last current location which was available!"));
    //      .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon_location)));

    // Showing the current location in Google Map
    mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(mLatLng));

    // Show Zoom buttons
    mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

    // Turns on 3D buildings
    mGoogleMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);

    // Zoom in the Google Map
    mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14));
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are getting your location using GPS and network. these are not giving your correct location and you are using:-

mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

this showing your location using google map api. so the loaction by you and google are different .so circle and marker are showing different location.

so you can use google's Fuesed Location client for this

Visit this for more help.
https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi.html